# How to parse optional inputs in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parameter-passing

I think [inputparser](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html) is doing that, but I couldn't find an example that shows how.

In my function, I define a struct named `opts` which contain the parameters that control the function. Example :

```
function y = f(x, extraOpts)
  opts= struct( ...
   'N', 100, ...
   'visualize', 1, ... % etc
  ); 
  do_things(x, opts);
end
```

Fields of `opts` have default values, but I want to be able to change them selectively. So I want to call the function with something like this:

```
f(x, {'visualize', 0});
```

in which case `.N` remains `100` but `.visualize` becomes `0`.

How can I achieve this with MATLAB? Also not sure if it will require the `extraOpts` parameter. I would of course prefer a way with `function y = f(x)` :)

Thanks for any help !

Comment: have you thought about varargin? http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html

Comment: As @FirefoxMetzger said, `varargin` is the standard solution. But it might work to use `f(x,extraOpts)` and check `nargin` at the beginning, setting the value of the optional variables based on how many are given.

Comment: Thanks, varargin seems to be very suitable for this. however, it requires the ordering of parameters, so I can parse `opts.N = varargin{3}`, but I need to know it's the 3rd argument beforehand. But I want to define them in any order, like `'N',10,'v',1` or the reverse, `'v',1,'N',10`. Can I do this with varargin? **Edit** btw I have much more fields in `opts`, let's say there are 10 fields, but I want to change only 3 of them at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use MATLAB's inputParser class:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html
http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2012/02/13/parsing-inputs/

**EDIT: I guess I'll just put the code in as well...**

```
function y = f(x, extraOpts)
    p = inputParser;
    p.addRequired('x', @(x) length(x)>1);
    p.addOptional('visualize', 1, @isscalar);
    p.addOptional('N', 100, @isscalar);
    p.parse(x, extraOpts{:});
    do_things(x, extraOpts);
end
```

You might need to store the results of the parse, perhaps something along the lines of:

```
inputs = p.parse(x, extraOpts{:});
do_things(inputs)
```

**END EDIT**

Alternatively, you could do something like redefine your function to take the number of values in your struct though it's not as powerful as the input parser solution:

```
function y = f(N, visualize)
if nargin < 2
  visualize = 0
end
if nargin < 1
  visualize = 0
  N = 100
end
```

Comment: Thanks Brock. The problem is I don't want to take them as constant inputs because there are lots of them, so I want to change a few at a time.

Comment: Then you should consider using the inputParser class, I've added the code as well though I don't have matlab on me at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. And how do I call this f? i.e. what do I supply as extraOpts?

Comment: It should be key value pairs e.g., {'visualize': 0}, I've updated the answer. You might need to play around with how you use the parsed inputs.

Comment: Very informative answer:) I just wanted to note that your last comment has a bit of a pythony feel to it;) Not that I would mind if we could use `dict`s in matlab.

Comment: Thanks Andras! Hahah yeah as far as interpreted languages go, I use Python the most so it's not surprising it pokes it's head out here and there :)

Comment: My point was to note to @HalilPazarlama that in matlab it goes like `f(x,'N',3,'visualize',0);`, so you add param-value pairs as (string-value) input variable pairs. Which also makes it possible to create a cell `opts={'N',3, 'visualize',0}` and then call `f(x,opts{:})`. Halil: note that the `{:}` in `opts{:}` is crucial: that turns the cell into a [comma separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html).

Comment: Ah, so while I said {'visualize': 0} , it should be {'visualize', 0} for Matlab. My mistake, thanks Andras! I honestly thought Matlab would have support for that, which you were alluding to ;)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to be cryptic in my first comment. Unfortunately, using a cell as input param-value pairs will only work with the `{:}` bit, but for that you have to assign it to a variable first. (Unlike python, where `f(x,**{'visualize': 0})` should be perfect, if I'm not mistaken. Shame.)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make the answer work, but I found another solution with inputParser, let me paste here for future reference :

```
function y = f2(extraOpts)
p = inputParser;
p.addParamValue('par1', 'defaultValue1');
p.addParamValue('par2', def2, @isnumeric);
p.addParamValue('par3', def3, @isnumeric);
p.parse(extraOpts{:});
extraOpts = p.Results;
end
```

the drawback is that I needed to separate the two inputs `x` and `extraOpts` and had to call `f2` as a subroutine, defined in the same file as `f`. Maybe there is a more elegant way for this (i.e. one that does not require another function), but the [example](https://github.com/ketch/RK-opt/blob/master/RK-coeff-opt/rk_opt.m) I have seen was also doing like that, and since it works, it's good for me :)